# unranking a sequence of all linear extensions of a partially ordered set

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory

- Let $P$ be a partially ordered set.
- Let $E$ be the set of all possible linear extensions of $P$.
- Let $S$ be the sequence formed by arranging elements of $E$ in lexicographic or graycode order.

Does an unranking function exist that maps $n$ to $S_n$?

In other words, does an efficient mapping exist between the set of linear extensions, and the set of corresponding lexicographic/gray codes (the same way it does for regular combinations and permutations)?

Comment: Do you mean does there exist a bijection $E\to S$? Of course there does. You need to fix a total order on $P$ to define a lexicographic order, and I'm not sure I understand what Gray code means in this context, but otherwise you're fine: ordering elements does not change their number.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code. Here its just an ordering where the next in the sequence differs by less than 2 position swaps.

I want to calculate the $n$th linear extension of $P$ without having to calculate $1...n-1$. With combinations there exists a rank/unrank function using the binomial coefficient.

Comment: If you want an efficient method, then you should say so explicitly, and not ask if a bijection exists; that means something quite different. Also your link says Gray code is an encoding of numbers, not of linear extensions of $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the Hasse diagram of the lattice of ideals of a given poset. All max length paths from source to sink in the digraph correspond to a linear extension. See section 2.2 and 3.2 of "Efﬁcient computation of rank probabilities in posets" by Karel De Loof and [Computing all simple paths in a distributive lattice in parallel.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510911/computing-all-simple-paths-in-a-distributive-lattice-in-parallel).

Once you have the graph, and the count information provided by section 3.2.2 of the above paper, an encoding scheme based on intervals can efficiently unrank the $n$th linear extension.
See: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16437/10979.