# Computing all simple paths in a distributive lattice in parallel.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, lattice-orders

(All arrows point downward.)

For the *poset* $P: 2 < 4, 1 < 3, 1 < 4, 3 < 5$ we get the graph:
[image]

A *linear extension* of this poset is $1,2,3,4,5$.

"A *downset* or *ideal* of a *poset* $(P, ≤)$ is a subset $D ⊆ P$
such that $x ∈ D, y ∈ P$ and $y ≤ x$ imply $y ∈ D$

If we consider the set of ideals $I(P)$ and equip it with the set inclusion
$⊆$, which is a partial order relation, a new poset $(I(P), ⊆)$ is obtained.
Moreover, it is more than a poset: it is a distributive lattice."

[image]

A linear extension of the original poset $P$ corresponds to a max length path in the lattice. Where traversing each node gives {NChild \ NParent}. Going down the middle path we get:
$2, 1, 3, 5, 4$ which is a valid linear extension of $P$.

Now the goal is to compute all linear extensions, in parallel on a multicore processor (a GPU to be specific).

For $P$ there are 9 linear extensions:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
 {1, 2, 3, 5, 4}, 
 {1, 2, 4, 3, 5}, 
 {1, 3, 2, 4, 5}, 
 {1, 3, 2, 5, 4}, 
 {1, 3, 5, 2, 4}, 
 {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}, 
 {2, 1, 3, 5, 4}, 
 {2, 1, 4, 3, 5}}
```

We can just perform a depth first search of the graph to obtain these, but this doesn't parallelize well. **What structural properties of distributive lattices can be used to open up more possibilities?**

The number of paths through a lattice describe many known sequences of numbers: Catalan etc. Can this information be used to generate an efficient unranking function? Where each thread is assigned an id from $ {1,2...n} $ and the function $Unrank(id) = {L,R,L,R,R,L}$ generates the corresponding branch decisions.

Comment: Your post has four votes to close because it is unclear what you are asking. Could you perhaps make your question more clear? And define more of your terms...

Comment: (If your post does get closed then you should edit it to make everything more clear and then it should get re-opened.)

Comment: @user1729: Sorry, is there any other aspect that is unclear?

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand your question now. (Although I am unsure about what the word "ideal" is doing there - is there an underlying ring?) Unfortunately, I cannot help you. (actually, I wonder if you would actually get a better response at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or at [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). If you get no response in a week or so here then you could try one of them, and link to this post so they won't just send you back here...)

Comment: Do you have the lattice $I(P)$ or just the partial order $P$?

Comment: Both, and also the spanning tree of $I(P)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient encoding system for all maximal paths exists. This unranking function maps nicely onto GPU threads.
See: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16437/10979

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have $(P,<)$ a finite poset. Consider the following algorithm:

```
extensions(P,start):
  extList = []
  for each x in P:
    if start < x:
      add all chains of the form (start, x, extensions(P-x,x)) to extList
  return extList
```

This can easily be parallelized. Namely, the `for` loop can be parallelized. You'll probably pass the point at which parallelization will yield benefits after 1 or 2 recursions, unless you have a huge cluster or a highly ordered set.

Comment: This still feels like a depth first search of the space, but without the memory overhead of the lattice. The problem remains though; how to effectively map the workload onto a GPU with 5000+ threads. Posets with 20 elements can easily reach 10^9 linear extensions.

So far, i can only think of two ways: 
1.) Expand breadth first on the CPU, until some halfway/optimal point, where the remaining work can be nicely mapped onto GPU threads.

2.) Sample extensions at random from the lattice, until all have been processed. 10^9 now becomes 10^11 to cover all extensions with 99% accuracy.

Comment: $20^3>5000$, so after 3 recursions you'd have more than enough separate tasks. So your (1) seems fine to me.